# Finding number of values in a column between 2 specific values

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and I am wanting to simply find out the number of values in a list between two latitudes.

I thought a simple if statement would suffice, but apparently not. My coding looks like this:

```
if lat < 62 & lat > 58:
    z = len(lat)
    print z
```

I then want to be able to get rid of repeated numbers. So how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is a [bitwise AND](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) operator. You should instead use [`and`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

Alternatively you can use [chained operators](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) as shown below:

```
if 58 < lat < 62:
    # do whatever you need to...
```

What you're actually trying to do is calculate how many of your latitudes are within the range (58, 62). In that case you can do `z = sum(58 < i < 62 for i in lat)`. This makes use of the fact that in Python `True` is equal to 1 and `False` is equal to 0. So if an element is within the range then it'll count as 1 and when you sum them all then only True (1) values will count up.

Comment: I then get this error though, which is confusing:                                                  Traceback (most recent call last): File "/net/home/h01/tdentjon/seals/csvdata/csvout/newdata/mean/Trial.py", line 53, in <module> if lat>58 and lat<62: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Aye, it is a list in a csv file.

Comment: So I have a range of values outside of 58 and 62, but I just want to find out the number of values between 58 and 62.

Comment: I see. I've updated the answer (leaving in the original problem between `&` and `and` for anyone who reads it in the future) and added how you can calculate the number of latitudes within your range using `sum()`.